# tvOS Is it possible to make UILabel accessible without making it focusable?

Tags: swift, tvos, uiaccessibility

In my tvOS app, I want to make my UILabel to read out when voice over enabled but at the same time I don't want to set my UILabel focusable. IS it at all possible? Adding focus to UILabel makes it accessible as well.

Answer (score 2):

Focusable by what?

If an element responds `YES` to `isAccessibilityElement` then it will be focusable by VoiceOver when the user has rotored to "Explore" mode. Note that in this mode VoiceOver focus is allowed to disassociate from the "native" tvOS focus.

If you have some contextual information conveyed by labels that aren't focusable by the focus engine, it may be appropriate to use the `accessibilityHeaderElements` API to have VoiceOver read these labels. The 2016 WWDC accessibility talk has some information near the end about how to use this API. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/202/

Answer (score 0):

Okay... after some research got to know it's not possible to make UILabel accessible without making it focusable.